# Conectar a SQL Server desde PHP en Úbuntu 16.04

Tags: php, sql-server, apache, ubuntu, apache2

Tengo una máquina con **Apache** y **PHP** instalado, necesito crear una conexión contra una base de datos **SQL Server** de una máquina de mi red, he instalado los `ODBC` y todo lo necesario usando las instrucciones de **Microsoft**.

Una vez instalado todo, borro el `index.html` del directorio `/var/www/html` y creo `index.php` con la siguiente estructura:

```
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.1.XXX"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Datos", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"XXXX");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Abro el navegador con la *ip de la máquina* y me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenés prendido el Apache ?? Tiene instalados los módulos para procesar PHP ??

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que no se haya vinculado de la manera correcta php con apache.

Para probar que la configuración es correcta puedes cambiar temporalmente el archivo por el siguiente código:

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Te debe mostrar una página con toda la información relacionada a tu php.

Si ves la pagina sin problema, puede ser que no tengas los drivers correctos. Prueba instalando los drivers `sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv` que habilitan el use de SQL SERVER con php.

Referencia:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu/step/2.html